# linear combinations of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

My goal is to find the basis vectors, and write the other vectors as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Attached is the original matrix and the reduced matrix

[Original Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt7JG.gif)

[Row Reduced Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er26L.gif)

I know that columns 1,2,4 are the basis vectors since they have leading ones. I tried writing the 3 basis vectors as {V1,V2,V4} | {V3,V5,V6} and solving for leading ones on the RHS but I don't think that is correct.

Since I am looking for the linear combination of V3,V5, and V6 from the 3 basis vectors I know that I need to write out something along the lines of

V3 = c1V1+c2V2+c4V4 which will give me V3.

I would prefer a bit of guidance in the right direction and *not* the answer.

Comment: By $V_n$ do you mean the $n$-th column of the reduced matrix?

Comment: Yes, so V1=[1,1,0,1,1,2]^T

Comment: Can't do you this by inspection? For example, $V_3 = 2V_1 + 2V_2$ because the first and second row of the third column have 2's?

Answer (score 1):

To find $V_3$, look first at the third entry. It tells you that $c_4 = 0$, so that gives you $V_3 = c_1V_1 + c_2V_2$. Now look at the second entry: necessarily $c_2 = 2$, and now it is easy to see that $c_1 = 2$, so that $V_3 = 2V_1 + 2V_2$, as you can check.

I tried to give you step-by-step solution to make it very clear...